# What is the meaning of the various fingering on this arpeggio?

Tags: piano, fingering, arpeggios

What is the meaning of the two fingerings : "3" and "4" in the D # minor arpeggio (second inversion) ?

Should I "choose" one ?
Is there an "academic/official" one ?

for the moment? I use the 4, and it is difficult at high speed, while with 3, it is very easy.

Should a pianist learn the two variantes ? (and why ?)

And what about for cases where there are two fingerings on the left hand and two fingers on the right hand (this is the case for D bemol sharp, 2nd inversion): should we learn 2x2=4 variantes ?

[image: to]

Answer (score 3):

Fingerings are suggestions and not commands. You can choose the one option, that you find is more comfortable.

You don't have to learn both fingerings at all, but you are invited to try out both suggestions. You also can  always write your own fingerings!

(I used to try sometimes looking for fingerings that where identical or symmetrical for both hands, even if they were less comfortable, but they helped me memorizing the musical motifs and the movement of my fingers ;)